# How to replace \n with < br > in escaped string?

Tags: javascript, html, regex, angularjs, escaping

I know similar questions have been asked before. In all the ones I am aware of I did not find a solution, and I have already tried several things on my own which I do not list for the sake of brevity.

In Angular I am trying to replace `\n` with `<br>` in an escaped string which looks like `ABC\nDEF\n\nGHI`.

I am using `var replaced = original.replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, "<br>")` which works fine if `original` has not been escaped.

How can I obtain the same when `original` has been escaped?

Comment: Seems to work for me: https://jsfiddle.net/Lan78g0h/1/.  What's the issue?

Comment: Yeah, this is working just fine for me, too. What browser are you testing on?

Comment: Firefox on Ubuntu. The string has been escaped through `jsesc` in a Node.js server and stored into a MongoDB database.

Comment: `.replace(/(?:\\r\\n|\\r|\\n)/g, "<br>")`?

Comment: @stribizhev Yes, finally! Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your string is escaped, you need to match literal backslashes.

Here is how you can match the linebreaks now:

```
var replaced = original.replace(/(?:\\r\\n|\\r|\\n)/g, "<br>");
```

In a literal notation, a double backslash matches a literal backslash.

Answer (score 0):

I might be misunderstanding the question, but wouldn't

```
var result = escaped.replace(/(\n)/g, '<br>');
```

Do the trick?

Comment: It does not work. I tried right away. And I think you mean  `.replace`instead of `.escaped`

Comment: I did, tried editing the variable name, edited the method name instead. Fixed it.

Comment: No need for the capture group: `/\n/g`